# Refer a usercontrol in a class

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I've created a user control, at this point I want to refer it in another class, but i can't find it, I receive the message:

> "The type or namespace name could not be found"

I've also tried to encapsulate the class in a namespace, but I can't find even the namespace in my other class.

The problem is that I haven't an aspx for insert the register tag...

How can I find it?

Comment: Close the solution and rebuild it completetely, then check the toolbox again, might be, this is as sometimes for c# winforms happens, even in VS2013

Comment: Change the user control's access modifier to public instead of private.

Comment: It would help to see the code of your user control, at least the definition part of it. We can't be sure what your problem is without seeing, we can only guess.

Comment: Did you remember to include a reference to the dll where that class is defined?